# How to Verify the table contains specific strings

Tags: c#, selenium, dynamic, webdriver

I am trying to verify if the table contains filetype (1st cell) is figure then 3ed cell should contain jpg or png, etc and 5th cell should contain (something)

the function should return true or false.
here is my code I don't know what I am doing wrong, because it always returns false even is the conditions are true. Thanks for the help !!

```
public bool Results()
{      
    var aqcTable = Browsers.getDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("table"));
    var lstTrElem = aqcTable.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
    var i = 0;
    foreach (var cell  in lstTrElem)
    {                         
        if (lstTrElem[i].Text== "figure")
            if (lstTrElem[ i+ 2].Text.Contains("jpg"))
                if (lstTrElem[i + 4].Text.Contains("pass"))
                        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: change the `lstTrElem` inside your loop (in your if conditions) to `cell`. You are trying to get the i the element of the tr collection, not the tr. `cell` points to a `tr` here.

Comment: All your conditions should return false. You are trying to check lstTrElem[i].Text, and lstTrElem[I] must be a `<tr>` here, and its text is, I don't know what.

Comment: I also recommend changing the loop variable name `cell` to `tableRow` or something. It causes confusion

Comment: Did it fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  when I change the lstTrElem  to the cell I get the error cell[I], could write it

Comment: Where did you change it? Please post the latest version of your code

Comment: I didn't know how to add the code to the comment, so I sent just like replying to my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the `Text` of a `<tr>` element.

You need to get the text of `<td>`. So if what you are trying to achieve is:

> I am trying to verify if the table contains filetype (1st cell) is
>   figure then 3ed cell should contain jpg or png, etc and 5th cell
>   should contain (something)

And you HTML content looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>fig_ure</td>
            <td>Some value</td>
            <td>jpg</td>
            <td>Some other value</td>
            <td>Some other value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Figure</td>
            <td>Some value</td>
            <td>jpg</td>
            <td>Some other value</td>
            <td>Some other value which contains the pass word</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: The text comparison is case sensitive. "figure" will not match "Figure"

Note: Name your variables as such, that the name should immediately convey what it holds

Note: First check existence and access later (tdElements.Count > 0 ?)

```
var firstTableElement = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("table"));
var trElementList = firstTableElement.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach (var trElement in trElementList)
{
    var tdElementList = trElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

    if (tdElementList.Count > 0)
    {
        bool trMatchesRequirements =
            tdElementList[0].Text == "figure" &&
            tdElementList[2].Text.Contains("jpg") &&
            tdElementList[4].Text.Contains("pass");

        if (trMatchesRequirements)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked!  , I did try to give feedback but I kept getting this popup    
         --------->Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score.